# Call function in a child with Flash CC

Tags: javascript, html, function, createjs, flash-cc

I have problem. I try to call function which is inside movieclip, but it doesn't work. I have 6 points (movieclips) and my code on main timeline is:

```
var point1 = this.point1;
var point2 = this.point2;
var point3 = this.point3;
var point4 = this.point4;
var point5 = this.point5;
var point6 = this.point6;

var points = [point1, point2, point3, point4, point5, point6];

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    points[i].resetPoint();
}
```

and this is my function inside every point which are copies of one movieclip and named properly:

```
this.resetPoint = function() {
    console.log("reset");
}
```

When i publish project and run it in browser, I get error:

> Uncaught TypeError: points[i].resetPoint is not a function

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Seems like a scoping issue, put this: console.dir(points[i]); in your loop.  You'll notice that there will not be a "resetPoint" function assigned to the points, this makes me think this.resetPoint is not pointing to the same scope.  Is there anyway you could toss up a fiddle or codepen or provide just a bit more code?

Comment: It is possible that this is being called before the first frame of the point instance has been processed, so the resetPoint is not defined yet.

Comment: @Lanny You`ve got right! I delayed calling function of 1 second and it works. Is it way to call this function without delayed? I call it now from this movieclip, but I want to control from any other place.

@Kyle I made dir like You said, but resetPoint was there, so problem what what @Lanny said.